# SQL join query to library

Tags: sql

I have these tables,

```sql
CREATE TABLE Book 
(
    ISBN CHAR(05)NOT NULL, 
    BKName VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL, 
    Author VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL, 
    Price NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT Book_PK PRIMARY KEY (ISBN) 
);
    
CREATE TABLE Location 
( 
    LoID CHAR(05)NOT NULL, 
    CityName VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL, 
    Stoke CHAR(05)NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT  Location_PK PRIMARY KEY (LoID) 
);
    
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(  
    CuID CHAR(05)NOT NULL,  
    CusName VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,  
    RegiDate DATE NOT NULL,  
    Gender VARCHAR(06)NOT NULL,  
    TeleNum CHAR(12)NOT NULL,  
    Address VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (CuID)  
);
    
CREATE TABLE BookCopy 
(  
    CopyID CHAR(05)NOT NULL,  
    ISBN CHAR(05)NOT NULL,  
    LoID CHAR(05)NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT pk_BookCopy PRIMARY KEY (CopyID),   
    CONSTRAINT fk_BookCopy_ISBN_FK FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) REFERENCES Book(ISBN),              
    CONSTRAINT fk_BookCopy_LoID_FK FOREIGN KEY (LoID) REFERENCES Location(LoID)
); 
    
CREATE TABLE BorrowRecord 
(
    BrrDate DATE NOT NULL,                 
    RetDate DATE NOT NULL,      
    BrFee NUMBER(05) NOT NULL,     
    Cus_Review NUMERIC(02)NOT NULL,      
    CopyID CHAR(05)NOT NULL,                                    
    CuID  CHAR(05) NOT NULL,           
    CONSTRAINT pk_BorrowRecord PRIMARY KEY (CopyID, CuID),       
    CONSTRAINT fk_BorrowRecord_CopyID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CopyID) REFERENCES BookCopy(CopyID) ,     
    CONSTRAINT fk_BorrowRecord_CuID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CuID) REFERENCES Customer(CuID) );
```

This is the task: "write and test a query to list the customer ID and name of every Customer along with the books that they have hired within the past 200 days. Include starting date, ending date, and location name for those hirings. All customer details (ID and name) should be included in the output, whether or not they have actually borrowed any books."

I write a query to list the customer ID and name of every Customer along with the books that they have borrowed within the past 200 days. Include starting date, ending date, and location name for those hirings. This the query for it.

```sql
SELECT 
    BorrowRecord.CuID, Customer.CusName, Book.ISBN, Book.BkName, 
    BorrowRecord.BrrDate, BorrowRecord.RetDate, Location.CityName
FROM 
    Book 
LEFT JOIN 
    BookCopy ON Book.ISBN = BookCopy.ISBN
LEFT JOIN 
    BorrowRecord ON BookCopy.CopyID = BorrowRecord.CopyID
LEFT JOIN 
    Customer ON BorrowRecord.CuID = Customer.CuID
LEFT JOIN 
    Location ON Location.LoID = BookCopy.LoID
WHERE 
    BorrowRecord.BrrDate >= sysdate - 200 ;
```

But I also need to get all customer details (ID and name) that should be included in the output, whether or not they have actually borrowed any books. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add the  tag for the dbms do you use and add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

If You want to see all customers independently whether they have borrowed a book or not, it's important that the first LEFT JOIN is based on customers table. In Your script, You start with Book, then join to BorrowRecord and only then have The Customer on the right side of the join. Another point is the WHERE -Condition that excludes all entries of Customer that borrowed a book outside of the 200-days-range. This meand that all records of BorrowRecord are shown (that match to the previous join) but only the customers that are found in a link to BorrowRecords from the past 200 days.
Try the following:

```
SELECT BorrowRecord.CuID, Customer.CusName, Book.ISBN, Book.BkName, 
BorrowRecord.BrrDate,BorrowRecord.RetDate, Location.CityName
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN BorrowRecord ON BorrowRecord.CuID = Customer.CuID
LEFT JOIN BookCopy ON BorrowRecord.CopyID = BookCopy.CopyID
LEFT JOIN Book ON BookCopy.ISBN= Book.ISBN
LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.LoID = BookCopy.LoID
WHERE ISNULL(BorrowRecord.BrrDate,'') >=sysdate-200 ;
```

Comment: . First of all i would like to  thank you for  your hellping. I try this your quary but error is comming " WHERE IS NULL(BorrowRecord.BrrDate,'') >=sysdate-200 "
      *

Comment: I think the empty output on the isnull is not permitted in Your database in relation to a date. Try ISNULL(BorrowRecord.BrrDate,'1900-01-01') >= sysdate-200. Maybe You must adjust the format of the date in the format of Your country settings.